# Why does awk seem to randomize the array?

Tags: arrays, awk

If you look at output of this `awk` test, you see that `array` in `awk` seems to be printed at some random pattern. It seems to be in same order for same number of input. Why does it do so?

```
echo "one two three four five six" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i} END {for (j in a) print j,a[j]}'
4 four
5 five
6 six
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

```
echo "P04637 1A1U 1AIE 1C26 1DT7 1GZH 1H26 1HS5 1JSP 1KZY 1MA3 1OLG 1OLH 1PES 1PET 1SAE 1SAF 1SAK 1SAL 1TSR 1TUP 1UOL 1XQH 1YC5 1YCQ" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i} END {for (j in a) print j,a[j]}'
17 1SAF
4 1C26
18 1SAK
5 1DT7
19 1SAL
6 1GZH
7 1H26
8 1HS5
9 1JSP
10 1KZY
20 1TSR
11 1MA3
21 1TUP
12 1OLG
22 1UOL
13 1OLH
23 1XQH
14 1PES
1 P04637
24 1YC5
15 1PET
2 1A1U
25 1YCQ
16 1SAE
3 1AIE
```

Why does it do so, is there rule for this?

Comment: if you want to get a fixed order, don't use `x in y`. use `for/while` since `x in y` won't keep the original order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [8. Arrays in awk --> 8.5 Scanning All Elements of an Array](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gawk-3.1.0/html_chapter/gawk_9.html#SEC137) in the GNU Awk user's guide when referring to the `for (value in array)` syntax:

> The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this
>   statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array
>   elements within awk and cannot be controlled or changed. This can lead
>   to problems if new elements are added to array by statements in the
>   loop body; it is not predictable whether or not the for loop will
>   reach them. Similarly, changing var inside the loop may produce
>   strange results. It is best to avoid such things.

---

So if you want to print the array in the order you store it, then you have to use the classical `for` loop:

```
for (j=1; j<=NF; j++) print j,a[j]
```

#### Example:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i} END {for (j=1; j<=NF; j++) print j,a[j]}' <<< "P04637 1A1U 1AIE 1C26 1DT7 1GZH 1H26 1HS5 1JSP 1KZY 1MA3 1OLG 1OLH 1PES 1PET 1SAE 1SAF 1SAK 1SAL 1TSR 1TUP 1UOL 1XQH 1YC5 1YCQ"
1 P04637
2 1A1U
3 1AIE
4 1C26
5 1DT7
6 1GZH
7 1H26
8 1HS5
9 1JSP
10 1KZY
11 1MA3
12 1OLG
13 1OLH
14 1PES
15 1PET
16 1SAE
17 1SAF
18 1SAK
19 1SAL
20 1TSR
21 1TUP
22 1UOL
23 1XQH
24 1YC5
25 1YCQ
```

Comment: Code and reference is all very good but this doesn't explain why, which is what Jotne asked.

Comment: @Jotne definitely not, the subtly is don't really on the *order* of `value in array`. It's a perfectly good construct if order doesn't matter.

Comment: I guess I missed a Jotne comment. Well, sure, the `for (i in a)` is pretty useful for many of the cases. Just unuseful if the order matters.

Comment: @fedorqui Ops deleted it accidentally :)  Question was id I should avoid using `value in array`

Comment: No problem, @Jotne :) As sudo_O cleverly said, you should not. It is a very useful tool that you just have to avoid when the order matters.

Answer (score 5):

Awk uses [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to implement associative arrays. This is just an inherent property of this particular data structure. The location that a particular element is stored into the array depends on the hash of the value. Other factors to consider is the implementation of the hash table. If it is memory efficient, it will limit the range each key gets stored in using the modulus function or some other method. You also may get clashing hash values for different keys so chaining will occur, again affecting the order depending on which key was inserted first.

The construct `(key in array)` is perfectly fine when used appropriately to loop over every key but you cannot count on the order and you should not update `array` whilst in the loop as you may end up process `array[key]` multiple times by mistake.

There is a good decription of hash tables in the book [Think Complexity](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022480.do).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is the operator you use to get the array indices, not the fact that the array is stored in a hash table.

The `in` operator provides the array indices in a random(-looking) order (which IS by default related to the hash table but that's an implementation choice and can be modified).

A `for` loop that explicitly provides the array indices in a numerically increasing order also operates on the same hash table that the `in` operator on but that produces output in a specific order regardless.

It's just 2 different ways of getting the array indices, both of which work on a hash table.

`man awk` and look up the `in` operator.

If you want to control the output order using the `in` operator, you can do so with GNU awk (from release 4.0 on) by populating `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal for details.

Some common ways to access array indices:

To print array elements in an order you don't care about:

```
{a[$1]=$0} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}
```

To print array elements in numeric order of indices if the indices are numeric and contiguous starting at 1:

```
{a[++i]=$0} END{for (i=1;i in a;i++) print i, a[i]}
```

To print array elements in numeric order of indices if the indices are numeric but non-contiguous:

```
{a[$1]=$0; min=($1<min?$1:min); max=($1>max?$1:max)} END{for (i=min;i<=max;i++) if (i in a) print i, a[i]}
```

To print array elements in the order they were seen in the input:

```
{a[$1]=$0; b[++max]=$1} END{for (i=1;i <= max;i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}
```

To print array elements in a specific order of indices using gawk 4.0+:

```
BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]=whatever} {a[$1]=$0} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}
```

For anything else, write your own code and/or see gawk `asort()` and `asorti()`.

Comment: Great overview. 
Are you using `in a` in lieu of `i<=length(a)` as part of `(i=1;i in a;i++)`, because the POSIX spec doesn't support the `length()` function for arrays, or is there another advantage to doing this?
Re `whatever`: supported values for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` are `"@ind_str_asc"`, `"@ind_num_asc"`, `"@val_type_asc"`, `"@val_str_asc"`, `"@val_num_asc"`, `"@ind_str_desc"`, `"@ind_num_desc"`, `"@val_type_desc"`, `"@val_str_desc"`, `"@val_num_desc"`, and `"@unsorted"`, or the name of a custom comparison function.

Comment: Yes, I've been using `in a` for longer than gawk has supported `length(a)` so I'm used to it and it's portable and for efficiency (and aesthetically) I hate the idea of calling the same function with the same args to produce the same result every iteration through a loop. If I weren't going to use `in a` then I'd set a variable outside of the loop and test that. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, thanks, but is calling `in a` in _every_ iteration actually more efficient than calling `length(a)`? Either way, I do get the point about caching the array size in a variable up front.

Comment: I've got to think `in a` is more efficient than `length(a)` since `in a` is just a builtin hash lookup while `length(a)` is a function call and calculating the number of elements in the array. So now I feel inspired to test it. After 3 timed runs of each script on an array of 1,000,000 elements, `in` is slightly faster than `length` but its close: `0m0.421s` vs `0m0.437s`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gawk or mawk, you can also set an env variable `WHINY_USERS`, which will sort indices before iterating.

Example:

```sh
echo "one two three four five six" | WHINY_USERS=true awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i} END {for (j in a) print j,a[j]}'
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
6 six
```

From `mawk`'s manual:

> WHINY_USERS
>
> This is an undocumented gawk feature.  It tells mawk to sort array indices before it starts to iterate over the elements of an array.