# AWK : Why does the for-loop take the second argument first?

Tags: for-loop, awk, split

Can someone explain me this behavior ?

```
$ echo "A_B_C_D" | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); for (i in a) {print i,a[i]}}'
2 B
3 C
4 D
1 A
```

Same with

```
$ awk '{split("A_B_C_D",a,"_"); for (i in a) {print i,a[i]}}' empty
2 B
3 C
4 D
1 A
```

Where empty is a file with one line.

However, this works :

```
$ echo "A_B_C_D" | awk '{n=split($0,a,"_"); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {print i,a[i]}}'
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

Thanks

Comment: The last example I gave ("This works) gives an ordered output. So the question I'd like to have an answer is, if the one I proposed, which is valid for gawk 3.1.0, is not valid for awk in MacOS, then, why this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man awk` and look up the `in` operator. If you want to control the output order using the `in` operator, you can do so with GNU awk by populating `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal for details.

Comment: What version of `gnu awk` supports `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`? Not supported on my Ubuntu running ver `3.1.8`

Comment: Looks like it's in 4.0, search for "sorted_in" at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/doc/gawk.info#n25241

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fedorqui, the answer was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683474/why-does-awk-seem-to-randomize-the-array):

And here is the best answer which satisfies my curiosity :

> From [8. Arrays in awk --> 8.5 Scanning All Elements of an Array](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gawk-3.1.0/html_chapter/gawk_9.html#SEC137) in the
>   GNU Awk user's guide (gawk 3.1.0) when referring to the for (value in array)
>   syntax:
>
> The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this statement
>   is determined by the internal arrangement of the array
>   elements within awk and cannot be controlled or changed. This can lead
>   to problems if new elements are added to array by statements in the
>   loop body; it is not predictable whether or not the for loop will
>   reach them. Similarly, changing var inside the loop may produce
>   strange results. It is best to avoid such things.

It's like python dictionary when looping over dict.keys(), isn't it ?

Comment: No idea about Python but that quote is incorrect for GNU awk in stating that the access order `cannot be controlled or changed`.

Comment: It's about awk not gawk.

Comment: There is no `awk`, all `awk`s are variants (there's gawk, tawk, mawk, nawk, POSIX awk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, BSD awk, etc. all with their own idiosyncracies) and in this case the quote you posted and which I'm addressing above is very clearly and explicitly about gawk: `...in the GNU Awk user's guide...`.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't know for the many awk, I'm on mac, which one have I? And what is the answer then ? And the GNU Awk user's guide above is version 3.1, which is why you found the quote incorrect.

Comment: idk but you could try `awk --version` and see what it tells you. My guess is it's BSD awk. Try running `awk 'BEGIN { printf "%s\n", NR==3 }'` and if you get a syntax error then that's BSD awk. I strongly advise you get the latest `gawk` as it has by far the most useful functionality of all available awks.

Comment: @EdMorton Ha! Boy thats some memory you got for knowing the limitations of each `awk` to identify version by it's failure. `:)`. You are indeed correct, Macs are shipped with BSD version of `awk` whose version info just says `awk version 20070501`