# How do you "normalize" a list of records with awk

Tags: awk

Say I have a tab-delimited list of records with two fields per record, like this

```
bobby joe, jr   a,b,c
sue smith       b,d
```

Imagine there is a TAB character between the name column and the column with the series of single letters.

The goal is to "normalize" the data so it looks like this:

```
bobby joe, jr   a
bobby joe, jr   b
bobby joe, jr   c
sue smith       b
sue smith       d
```

I would like to learn how to do this specifically with `awk`.

Comment: The delimiter is a tab character. There are no tabs in the name field or the field with the comma-separated letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use define `spaces*` or `comma` as possible delimiters and then loop through the string printing the first field plus another, just like this:

```
$ awk -F" *|," '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i}' file
bob a
bob b
bob c
sue b
sue d
```

---

Given the updated question, with `data` TAB `records`, you can split the `records` like this:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '{n=split($2,a,","); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1, a[i]}' file
bobby joe, jr a
bobby joe, jr b
bobby joe, jr c
sue smith b
sue smith d
```

#### Explanation

- `-F"\t"` sets tab as field separator.
- `n=split($2,a,",")` slices the 2nd field in pieces given the `,` separator. As `split()` returns the number of pieces, we store that number in `n`.
- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1, a[i]` loops through the pieces and prints them together with the first field.

Comment: But what if I had tab-delimited fields, and the 2nd field (not shown, but between the 1st and 3rd field) might contain spaces or commas?

Comment: Then you'd better update your question showing some sample input like that.

Comment: @dan just change `-F" *|,"` to `-F"\t|,"`

Comment: @veryhungrymike please see the latest updated version of the question

Comment: @dan just edited to answer this `data` TAB `records` new input file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pretty printing and the whole shebang:

```
$ echo  -e "bobby joe, jr\ta,b,c\nsue smith\tb,d" \
    | awk -F"\t" '
BEGIN {MaxLen = 0} 
{
    a[NR] = $0; 
    if (length($1) > MaxLength) { 
        MaxLength = length($1)
    }
} 
END { 
    for (i in a) { 
        split(a[i], Fields); 
        split(Fields[2], Values, ","); 
        for (j = 1; j <= length(Values); j++) {
            printf("%-"MaxLength"s\t%s\n", Fields[1], Values[j])
        }
    }
}'
bobby joe, jr   a
bobby joe, jr   b
bobby joe, jr   c
sue smith       b
sue smith       d
```

Comment: Note that you can loose the order if you just loop with `for (i in values)`. See [Why does awk seem to randomize the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20683474/1983854) for more reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to give it to @fedorqui though because he posted first & dealt with my edits.

Comment: @fedorqui I'm aware of that. OP didn't specify that order was important. It's easier for me to just use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` but some people aren't current in their gawk versions.