# Parsing of ip address from netstat output on MacOS with awk

Tags: macos, awk

This is an awk related question (no perl/cut/sed... please :) ).

What I'm actually trying to do is to get the destination address from netstat output on MacOS using only awk.

Here an example of the output:

```
$ netstat -nl -p tcp
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.26164        127.0.0.1.50100        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.50100        127.0.0.1.26164        ESTABLISHED
```

If I run the awk parser, I get :

```
$ netstat -nl -p tcp | awk '/tcp/ {split($5,a,".") ; for(i=1; i<NF-1; i++) printf a[i] "."; printf "\n"}'
127.0.0.1.
127.0.0.1.
```

1) Is there a way to remove the "." at the end of the IP address?

2) Is there a better "awk" way to obtain the same result?

PS: I know you can type something like

```
$ netstat -nl -p tcp | perl -ape '$_=$F[4];s/((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\D.*/$1\n/'
```

to get the correct result ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just play with the number of elements coming from `split()`:

```
awk '/tcp/ {n=split($5,a,".")
            ^-----------------------------------------------------------\
            for(i=1; i<n; i++) printf "%s%s", a[i], (i==n-1?"\n":".")   |
                       ^-----------------------------^^^^^^-------------/
           }'
```

#### Explanation

- `n=split($5,a,".")` split as you were doing, but storing in the variable `n` the amount of fields that this produces.
- `for(i=1; i<n; i++) printf "%s%s", a[i], (i==n-1?"\n":".")}` loop through these values, printing either a dot `.` or a new line depending on the loop time.

#### Test

```
$ netstat ... | awk '/tcp/ {n=split($5,a,"."); for(i=1; i<n; i++) printf "%s%s", a[i], (i==n-1?"\n":".")}'
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The other reply is probably better but here's my attempt:

```
netstat -nl -p tcp | awk '/tcp/{split($5,a,".");for(x in a)if(a[x+1]""){y=y SEP a[x]; SEP="."}print y;y="";SEP=""}'
```

**Explanation**

- `if(a[x+1]"")` checks if there is a next element in an array (i.e. if it's not processing the last element - the port) and the `""` converts the number into a string by applying concatenation so `0` doesn't evaluate to `False`
- The `SEP` variable just makes sure the output won't start with a `.`, and gets reset at the end.

Comment: This `for (i in a)` may cause problems. See [Why does awk seem to randomize the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20683474/1983854). As the order matters, I would recommend you to stick to the `for(i=0; i...)` syntax.

Comment: Works on my machine. Kidding, but I tried with a larger set of inputs, and it still didn't randomise. Using ``GNU Awk 4.1.`` https://paste.ee/p/07ztE

Comment: Yep, I see, but you can never know. Also, I would suggest adding some braces to make it more clear what is the scope of the `for` --> `awk '/tcp/{split($5,a,"."); for(x in a) {if(a[x+1]""){y=y SEP a[x]} SEP="."} print y; y="";SEP=""}' file`. I am not a big fan of this solution, because assigns `SEP` repeatedly and would be best to make use of the output of `split()`. However, +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think I prefer this approach with multiple alternative `FS` - either dot or space:

```
netstat -nl -p tcp |awk -F'[. ]*' '/tcp/{print $9,$10,$11,$12}' OFS="."
```

Comment: @fedorqui Ooops, thank you! I mis-read the question - actually understanding he wanted the 4th-7th columns :-)

Comment: Thanks, I like both ways. I was not able to use the OFS... I missed the asterisk in the separation field option.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it the UNIX way? Pipe it to another utility:

```
netstat -nl -p tcp | awk '/tcp/{print $4}' | sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//'
```

Or, to do the whole thing in `awk`, use `sub()` to delete the last part of the IP:

```
netstat -nl -p tcp | awk '/tcp/{sub(/\.[0-9]*$/,"",$4); print $4}'
```

Unfortunately, BSD `grep` (which is what OSX has) does not have the `-P` option, else you could do:

```
netstat -nl -p tcp | awk '/tcp/{print $4}' | grep -oP '.*(?=\.\d+)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest and most general way to do this using awk

```
 awk '{match($5,/(.*)\./,x);print x[1]}' file
```

Comment: Actually doesn't work with awk but gawk. Anyway, that was exactly what I was thinking about, the shortest and elegant solution :) ). Thanks!