# bash script count each lines and some fields

Tags: bash, shell, awk

i need to count each connections from the each provider
,connections are in first column last provider , final output must be sum of the each operator

```
15 48502416383, orange:
2 48502416400, orange:
1 48601130989, plus:
3 48601131238, plus:
1 48782988324, plus:
4 48500182073, orange:
4 48694480239, era:
7 48697044484, orange:
4 48783915134, orange:
5 48512807390, orange:
11 48602570756, era:
12 48504126777, orange:
12 48507000833, orange:
18 48604089990, era:
19 48607629812, orange:
19 48880458754, era:
20 48515114454, orange:
29 48604089930, era:
31 48602240259, era:
37 48605110152, plus:
50 48608646173, era:
74 48783937132, era:
```

it's should look like this

```
plus 42
orange 100
era 236
```

Comment: Anything you've tried? Anywhere you're stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` loves these things:

```
awk '{a[$3]+=$1} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
```

It returns:

```
orange: 100
plus: 42
era: 236
```

This stores the sum in an array `a[]`, being the third column the index. Once the file has been fully processed, in the `END` block, it loops through the array printing the results.

---

To get rid of the colon `:`, you can use (thanks [Cyrus for the recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525853/bash-script-count-each-lines-and-some-fields/26525900?noredirect=1#comment41679674_26525900)):

```
awk -F"[ :]" '{a[$3]+=$1} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' a
```

It returns:

```
plus 42
orange 100
era 236
```

By saying `-F"[ :]"` we indicate that the field separator can be either a space (the default) or the colon. This way, the 3rd column will just be `orange`, instead of `orange:`.

Comment: Consider to add `-F '[ :]'`

Comment: True! Good one. I found it handy to have just space, so that the output shows the colon and makes it more nicely displayed. Updated, thanks!

Comment: and it changes the output order - but I don't know why. I've updated your answer.

Comment: @Cyrus This is because of the `for (i in a)`. See [Why does awk seem to randomize the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20683474/) for more info.