# How to move some lines to the top of the file?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, ash

I have a file like this:

```
aaa.bbb.1.ccc
xxx.bbb.21
mmm.ppp
xxx.eee
mmm.qqqq
xxx.hhh.12.ddd
```

I want to move all the lines starting with `xxx.` at the top of the file with a simple command (using `sed`, `awk`, `grep`...).

So my new file will look like this:

```
xxx.bbb.21
xxx.eee
xxx.hhh.12.ddd
aaa.bbb.1.ccc
mmm.ppp
mmm.qqqq
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 6):

One [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution:

```
sed -n '/^xxx/! { H }; // p; $ { x; s/^\n//; p }' infile
```

The `H` appends the content that does not begin with `xxx` to the *hold space*, and the opposite match is printed inmediatly `// p`. At last line `$` recover the *hold space* contents, remove leading newline character and print.

It yields:

```
xxx.bbb.21
xxx.eee
xxx.hhh.12.ddd
aaa.bbb.1.ccc
mmm.ppp
mmm.qqqq
```

Comment: An alternative solution but in the same vein: `sed '/^xxx/p;//!H;$!d;x;s/\n//' file`

Answer (score 4):

You can process the file twice with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {if (/^xxx\./) {print; a[FNR]} next} !(FNR in a)' file file
xxx.bbb.21
xxx.eee
xxx.hhh.12.ddd
aaa.bbb.1.ccc
mmm.ppp
mmm.qqqq
```

In the first one, we match the lines starting with `xxx.` and: print them, store its number. In the second reading of the file, we just skip those stored lines.

Answer (score 3):

Another `awk`

```
awk '!/^xxx/ {a[$0];next} 1; END {for (i in a) print i}' file
xxx.bbb.21
xxx.eee
xxx.hhh.12.ddd
aaa.bbb.1.ccc
mmm.ppp
mmm.qqqq
```

`!/^xxx/` If line does not start with `xxx`
`a[$0];next` store it in array `a`
`1` print line with `xxx`
`END {for (i in a) print i}` At end print lines in array `a`. (the one without `xxx`)

---

As fedorqui (thank you) points out, if order of lines are important, use this:

```
awk '!/^xxx/ {a[++c]=$0;next} 1; END {for (i=1;i<=c;i++) print a[i]}' file
xxx.bbb.21
xxx.eee
xxx.hhh.12.ddd
aaa.bbb.1.ccc
mmm.ppp
mmm.qqqq
```

Comment: note this maybe does not preserve the order ([your own question!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20683474/1983854))

Answer (score 3):

Another awk for those not in the mood to use arrays:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { if (/^xxx/) print; next } !/^xxx/' top.txt top.txt
xxx.bbb.21
xxx.eee
xxx.hhh.12.ddd
aaa.bbb.1.ccc
mmm.ppp
mmm.qqqq
```

`NR == FNR { if (/^xxx/) print; next }` First pass, print lines starting with xxx
`!/^xxx/` Second pass, print lines not starting with xxx

Comment: You can write this `top.txt top.txt` like this `top.txt{,}`

Comment: @jas, Why do you need to equate NR==FNR? Can you please explain the purpose of it

Comment: Sure, @Sadhun, it's actually quite well explained here: http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/  (search for the section headed "Two-file processing").  In this case, of  course, instead of process two files we're processing the same file twice (putting the file on the command line twice). As `NR` is the total number of recs read by awk until this point, and `FNR` is the number of recs within the current file, when `NR == FNR` we know we are reading the file for the first time. The `next` keps awk from going to the next statement, which therefore can only be reached on second readng

Comment: @jas - I got the answer. NR==FNR will run the first operation in first file and once fails it goes for next operation in second file

Answer (score 2):

With **grep**:

```
grep "^xxx" File > NewFile && grep -v "^xxx" File >> NewFile
```

Redirect all lines starting with `xxx` to file `NewFile`. Then grep for lines `not starting` with `xxx` and append to `NewFile`.

It uses `&&` between commands, so that one is not executed if the former exited with the bad status.

Comment: you probably want to say `&&` instead of `;`. This way, the final `mv tmp File` won't be done if something failed before. Otherwise, you may end up truncating `File`.

Comment: or `{ grep ; grep ; } > NewFile`. Bad new is 2 subshell at least but very fast on huge file

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^xxx/!{H;$!d;}
     ${x;s/.//;}' YourFile
```

using the `d` behaviour (cycle without going further in script)