# Remove duplicate line based on non-numerical condition in a single field in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Raw Data:

```
    1234,yes
    2234,no
    1234,no
    5678,yes
```

I was trying to remove duplicate based on the 2nd column (Yes||No) in which only the one with 'no' will be removed. I saw a lot of solutions that deal with integer, but not with string. So far I came up with this.

```
awk -F"," '{if($1 in a)
               a[$1]=$2=='yes'?$0:a[$1];
            else
               a[$1]=$0}
           END{for(i in a)print a[i]}'
```

However, what the script does not seem to work, as it removes all the duplicated entry.  If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is pretty simple : you have forgotten to quote correcty your condition :

```
awk -F"," '{if($1 in a)a[$1]=$2=="yes"?$0:a[$1];else a[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}'
```

You have to write *$2=="yes"* and not *$2=='yes'*

**Edit:**
For not showing ",no" at the final result, you can try this variation (more difficult to adapt your demand on the previous pattern) :

```
 awk -F"," '{if($1 in a){if($2=="yes"){a[$1]=$0;}}else{sub(/,no$/,"",$0);a[$1]=$0}}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}'
```

For more information about *sub(...)* function, you can go [there](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html).

Glad to help you :)

Comment: Using `i in a` in the `END` section, will randomize the output.  Not sure if that is a problem.

Comment: Doesn't it work like a foreach ? I never had a problem with this syntax.

Comment: Output of your code (you should always post output of code in answer if its not to long) is `1234,yes` `5678,yes` `2234,no`.  If you look at plesivs solution he get: `1234,yes` `2234,no` `5678,yes`.  See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683474/why-does-awk-seem-to-randomize-the-array

Comment: My output is not sorted, but it works. And you can see plesiv's solution does not work if you add '2234,yes' in the end of the file.

Comment: I am wondering if there is way to print a specific column , rather than the whole fields. For example, 1234 rather than (1234,no)

Answer (score 1):

[ If I understood correctly what you're trying to do... ]

This one-liner removes only `"no"` lines when value of the first column already appeared either in the prior `"yes"` line or the prior `"no"` line.

```
awk -F"," '{if (!($2=="no" && $1 in a)) {print $0;} a[$1]=$0 }' file.txt
```

Comment: This can be written like this: `awk -F, '!($2=="no" && $1 in a); {a[$1]=$0}' file`