# How can I remove the rows with the same first column and lower second column in awk?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a list with 2 columns. In some rows I have the same values in the first column. In this case I want to remove the rows with lower values in the second column.
example:
input:

```
1  10
2  20
3  15
3  5
3  35
4  20
```

output:

```
1  10
2  20
3  35
4  20
```

Comment: please show us the code you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=(a[$1]<$2?$2:a[$1])} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
1 10
2 20
3 35
4 20
```

Just keep populating the array `a[]` with the maximum value of column 2 for a given column 1. Finally, print the result.

This uses the fact that a value defaults to `0` in awk. But it would fail if all values for a certain index were always negative or zero. For this, we have to improve the script a little bit by checking also if the specific index of the array exists:

```
awk '{a[$1]=(($1 in a) && a[$1]>$2?a[$1]:$2)}
     END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
1  10
2  20
3  -15
3  -5
3  -35
4  20
$ awk '{a[$1]=(($1 in a) && a[$1]>$2?a[$1]:$2)} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}'  a
1 10
2 20
3 -5
4 20
```

Comment: You are right. I thought about it, but having the sample input with positive values lead me to the "easy" approach.

Comment: In fact I normally think on the easy approach and then add the sanity checks. I just added it, then I noticed it is almost exactly the same you suggested in your previous comment!

Comment: @EdMorton You should either write a book! Or at least start writing canonic question/answers in this site, so that they are easy to find and not "dirtied" by user specific situations. See for example what they did in Unix&Linux: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/lets-compile-a-list-of-canonical-qas

Comment: Yeah some day..... At one point I had been contributing solutions to awk.info (see http://awk.info/?EdM) but the guy who owns the site quit so now unfortunately it's unmaintained and I certainly don't want to take THAT job on!

Comment: @fedorqui I think there is no guarantee, that the lines will be printed sorted by index. This may depend on the awk used.

Comment: @Meixner true, this has been discussed in [Why does awk seem to randomize the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20683474/1983854)