# How to count the number of lines between pattern with awk or other console tool?

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk

I have such input:

```
*** dev1
result1
result2
other3
*** dev2
result1
result2
```

I would like to count lines after `***` and display them like this:

```
*** dev1
3
*** dev2
2
```

Is this possible with awk or other bash tools?

Comment: "Is this possible...?" Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
awk '/\*\*\*/ {if (count) print count; print; count=0; next} {count++} END {print count}' file
```

For your sample input it returns:

```
*** dev1
3
*** dev2
2
```

To match consecutive blocks (that is, two lines with `***` one after the other), we can check `NR` (number of line) instead of `count`:

```
awk '/\*\*\*/ {if (NR>1)print count; print; count=0; next} {count++} END {print count}' file
```

Comment: This won't display a count if there're no lines between two `***` lines (which may be ok for the OP though)

Comment: @eugeney good point. Probably `awk '/\*\*\*/ {if (NR>1)print count; print; count=0; next} {count++} END {print count}' file` solves it, because `count` is not evaluated (the original problem when it was 0) but just the number of line.

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl:

```
$ perl -lne '/\*\*\*/ && do {print $c if defined $c; $c = 0; print} || $c++; END {print $c}' file
*** dev1
3
*** dev2
2
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with `awk`:

```
awk '/\*\*\* /{p=$0} {a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"\n"a[i]-1}' File
```

Whenever the pattern `***` is matched, assign the entire line to variable `p`. Increase `a[p]` (this will be the counter) for every line. In the `END`, use array `a[]` to print the patterns and count. (`-1` used since count is increased even for lines with `***`). Output might not be always sorted, which i assume is not a concern here.

Output:

```
AMD$ awk '/\*\*\* /{p=$0} {a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"\n"a[i]-1}' File
*** dev1
3
*** dev2
2
```

Comment: He is just counting the line below a header in the array. After all, for me it looks like the best solution.

Comment: Note that the order can be lost: [Why does awk seem to randomize the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20683474/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui, easy enough to fix if it was a problem though.