# extract the number of lines using shell

Tags: shell

I have a ansible host file with different groups of hosts. I want to extract the number of hosts under a specific group. I am trying to use linux command but unable to get the correct command

Following is the content of the host file

```
[Mysql_host]

ip1
ip2

[jenkins_host]

ip3
ip4
```

I want to extract the number of hosts under each group. I am unable to find the linux command to extract those hosts. Please help

Comment: what is the number of hosts under the first group, for example?

Comment: The number of hosts on each group varies. There is no fixed number of hosts under each group.

Comment: so do you want to extract `ip1`, `ip2`, ... or their number 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
awk '/\[/{p=$0} /./{a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"\n"a[i]-1}' inputfile
```

I got most of this from [How to count the number of lines between pattern with awk or other console tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781836/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-between-pattern-with-awk-or-other-console-tool)

It assumes that anything containing an opening square bracket is a hostname, and it assumes that any non-empty line is countable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I wanted @Chris Lear